# Как реализовать динамический promise?

Tags: mysql, node.js, promise

требуется последовательно выполнить несколько sql запросов к MySQL

вызов команд реализую через Promise

но встал вопрос как сделать универсальный метод обрабатывающий последовательно массив запросов?

более конктретно как на Promise реализовать такую цепочку вызовов?

```
class myClass() {

    constructor() {
        this.list = [sq1,sql2,sql3];
    }   

    function myFunc(i) {

        ...

        if(++i < list.length) {

            if(...) list.push(newSQL); <= {1} <=

            this.myFunc(i)
        }
    }
}

let m = new MyClass();
m.myFunct(0);
```

`UPDATE`

сейчас так реализована одна итерация, вопрос как последовательно обработать весь список:

```
    myBuy(sql) {

        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

            ...

            let promise = global._query(sql);

            promise
            .then(
                data=>resolve(data),
                err=>reject(err)
            )
        })

    }


listSQL.forEach((e) => 
    myClass.myBuy(e)
)
```

Comment: вы хотите, чтобы promise выполнялись одна за одной последовательно? параллельно? в случае неудачи одной что будет с остальными?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman, последовательно. Неудача в данной задаче не критична. Вопрос как `Promise.all` сделать последовательным и обрабатывающим динамический (дополняемый) массив.

Comment: дополняемый в какой момент?

Comment: дополнил код, посмотрите строчку с `{1}`.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman, хотя динамичность здесь не принципиальна. Больше вопрос в `последовательности`

Comment: а где promise? получается, что вы внутри функции хотите изменять массив и рекурсивно ее вызывать? а зачем так сложно? почему просто не пройтись по массиву **forEach**?

Comment: `p = p.then(yetAnotherPromise)` не подходит?

Comment: SQL- это транзакции, обрабатывающие одни таблицы, будет конкуренция за ресурсы

Comment: @MikhailVaysman, `forEach` сгенерирует несколько параллельных sql-команд?

Comment: Я думаю будет проще, если вы добавите в вопрос задачу которую решаете.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman, обновил вопрос

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно что-то вроде этого "наваять", но я бы рекомендовал использовать готовые библиотеки.
Когда-то для подобных вещей я использовал [async](https://caolan.github.io/async/)

```js
let list = [
  Promise.resolve(1),
  Promise.resolve(2),
];

const add = (p, newP) => 
  p.then(results => newP.then(newRes => {
    results.push(newRes);
    return results;
  }));


let p = Promise.resolve([]);
list.forEach(newP => p = add(p, newP));

p = add(p, Promise.resolve(3));
p = add(p, Promise.resolve(4));

p.then(results => console.log(results));

p = add(p, Promise.resolve(5));
p.then(results => console.log(results));
```